# How does StackOverflow generate profile picture dynamically?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar

I am curious how Stack Overflow generates profile pictures randomly in cute way. What is the best way to achieve that? What tools or programming knowledge I should know?

Comment: http://gravatar.com

Comment: I don't see how this belongs on Meta. It's not specific to the Stack Exchange sites and (at the root) a programming problem.

Comment: @slhck: The *solution* is likely to be more general, but the question is about Stack Exchange, and a Stack Exchange specific answer would presumably be acceptable.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

Comment: @slhck It could go either way. Having this on meta is probably the safest, actually, considering that Stack Overflow generally frowns on "what tools do I need to do something like website X does it" type of questions.

Comment: @Anna Of course. I hope it didn't sound like I wanted this particular version of the question to stay on SO either.

Comment: @slhck the OP had no clue that Stack Overflow is using Gravatar, this question is totally legitimate here in my opinion. Now that he knows he might ask "How Gravatar generates the dynamic picture?" and this indeed won't belong here.

Answer (score 8):

It's a site called [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com) that provides that service.

It generates those images from your email address or your IP address...

Comment: And, some look like swastikas!